# Does Azure AD public keys endpoint has a limit?

Tags: python, azure, azure-active-directory, fastapi, public-key

Im working on an api and using azure AD as auth method.
My question is if the public endpoint for the keys "https://login.microsoftonline.com//discovery/keys?appid=" has a call limit?
So if i have around 3000 calls an hour to our api that would mean 3000 calls an hour to the endpoint. the implementation that we have right now is having the keys in our instance, the problem with this is that lately these keys have been changing without me noticing and that results in some requests having troubles.

My go to idea was to have a cron job to check these keys every a few hours and update them in s3 and from the api get the file of the keys from s3 on every request (i guess this will slow us a little so any other ideas apreciated), but i want to know if its possible to just call the public key endpoints without microsoft banning or limiting us.

By the way, im working with Python/fastAPI.

Thanks for reading, hope everyone has a great day!

Comment: Do the keys have an expiration time?  You shouldn't have to poll for new keys.

Comment: Im not really sure, i thought they didnt had, we never had any troubles with them until a month or two ago that we started having troubles and we realized that the keys had changed, from that time to now we had to update them 3 times.

Comment: Aparently they do change from time to time, i just found this in the ad docs:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/access-tokens#validating-the-signature - "A reasonable frequency to check for updates to the public keys used by Microsoft Entra ID is every 24 hours."

Comment: `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits` here are the limitations

Comment: Thanks! im going to take a look there

Comment: i have read that but wast able to find any on this. maybe im reading it wrong or looking for the wrong thing